# Combobox (select component) in angular not setting display value based on a parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, combobox

I 've been searching for this topic and found many approaches, but until now I was not able to find something that matches what I need.

I have the following code at controller level:

```
controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {            
        $scope.rawDownloads = [{name: 'QA environment', month: 'Dec'}, {name: 'Production environment', month: 'Feb'}, {name: 'UAT environment', month: 'Jul'}];
        $scope.availableMonths = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];                       
      }
```

What I'm doing in the view part is the following:

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
  <td>Environment Name</td>
  <td>Current Release Month</td>
</tr>
<tr data-ng-repeat="e in rawDownloads">
  <td>{{e.name}}</td>  
  <td><select id="{{e.name}}" name="{{e.name}}" ng-model="selectedMonth" ng-options="m as m for m in availableMonths"></select></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

"rawDownloads" is actually data that comes from a service, a simple array with more elements and some other properties, but I'm just summarizing this to make it simpler.

As you can see I should have three rows and each row should have a select component. I'm having problems displaying the "select" component for each row, it displays the months from Jan to Dec for each one (no problem until that part); however, the first index is always a blank space, I'm not really sure how to remove this, but the main issue comes when I try to set the default value for the select component. For instance, the first row that belongs to "QA environment" should default the value of the select option to "Dec", but each time I use `ng-init` to make default the value of month from rawDownloads, the whole thing gets messed. I tried with `ng-model` trying to set `ng-model="{{e.month}}"` but not results neither.

Could somebody provide feedback on this issue? I've been trying this even with `<select>` and the `<options>` tag using "ng-repeat" but no success at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want default values , you can set `ng-model="e.month"`

```
<select id="{{e.name}}" 
    name="{{e.name}}" 
    ng-model="e.month" 
    ng-options="m as m for m in availableMonths">
</select>
```

see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bZX7Q/80/

Comment: man, I hate myself for not seeing the answer in front of my eyes, but that's the cost of being new to this framework.You certainly saved my life. This works perfect. Thank you very much.